# Unable to load assembly error deploying x64 ASP.NET web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, 64-bit, badimageformatexception

I have developed an ASP.NET web application consisting only of generic http handlers. 
I started on a x86 development machine tested locally using IISExpress, then deployed on a 32bit Windows 2003 Server with IIS6.0, and everything went well.

My company decided to update to an x64 environment in order to take advantage of some third party libraries that are optimized for 64bit environments, hence we switched to a 64bit Windows Server 2012 R2 std edition, but I'm having some troubles.

On my local machine, now switched to a x64 dev machine with platform target set to x64 everything goes well, but when deploying on the server I always get

> System.BadImageFormatException

on the main assembly. Other part of the error message says that the assembly manager is loaded by

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll

and it is executed with

> C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe

Since SysWOW64 it is needed to run 32bit applications inside 64bit environments, it is possible that IIS server on the production machine is not enabled to run x64 web applications?
If so what should I do to overcome this issue, knowing that I do not have direct access to the server.

Thank you.

Comment: what do you have the properties setup as at the project ->properties...? 
`tell us what the PlatForm Taraget` is this sounds like this is where the issue lies

Comment: Platform Target is set to x64

Comment: well either set it to `Any` or `x86` can you try that and report back on if making the changes fix the issue

Comment: yes sure. but in the end I will need to compile with Platform Target set to x64 because of the third party library and the fact that we need to use Oracle.Data.Access that is suggested to be compiled for the specific platform.

Comment: `actually I disagree` especially in regards to Oracle.. I had this issue last week and I had to download the 32bit version for Oracle and the 64bit version for .net in regards to Oracle has a serious `BUG` ...

Comment: Ok, I need to think about that. Anyway currently I am not linking any third party DLLs, there are just .NET Framework DLLs. Compiling both with Platform Target set to AnyCpu or x86 gives me the same error

Comment: You mentioned `Oracle 64bit` I'm telling you that you won't be able to use it even if you have an operating system that's 64bit if you just download and install the Oracle .net 32bit client `ver 11.2.x` it will resolve your issues and you will need to set the properties in the project to `x86` under the build.. `Install the 32bit client side by side` meaning `do not uninstall 64bit Oracle Client`

Comment: I understand and thank you for your advices. But I am saying that I am getting this error even without linking any third party library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error and the paths:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
```

and

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
```

...definitely prove that the production server you're deploying to is running its website application pools in 32 bit mode, or certainly yours anyway.

As a web hoster we do the same for a bunch of legacy reasons. Have a word and see if they'll flip it back to native 64 bit mode.

Comment: This was the problem, 32bit mode was enabled for the application pool.